# Facebook extended permissions from canvas application

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm create a Facebook canvas application that will be require extended permissions, for both images (creating galleries, and uploading images) and posting to a users news feed. I'm having trouble with extended permissions. What is the correct way to do this through Javascript or PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history'
        )
);
```

Change req_perms into what you actually need

Source: http://thinkdiff.net/?p=1767